# How can I get a graph of graphs to display in Sage?

Tags: networkx, sage

I am working in SageMathCloud and have the following code:

```
import networkx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test5 = networkx.Graph()
example = graphs.BuckyBall
test5.add_node(example)
networkx.draw(test5)
plt.show()
```

and from what I read, should display a graph with a single vertex that has a graph inside of it, like this picture from [this article](http://www.math.toronto.edu/~rafi/gofg.html).[image: this picture] However, all it shows is a single vertex with nothing inside of it as shown: [image: idk] Is there any way to display the graph to look like the 1st picture, where the graphs (as vertices) are shown?

Comment: Since you're using networkx I'm not sure if they support that.  Sage itself does support different labels for the graphs, but you might have to hack the code to get it to display this kind of thing - which could be worthwhile.

Comment: You should try asking on the Networkx mailing list or in some sort of Networkx forum.  Also, try writing to the author of http://www.math.toronto.edu/~rafi/gofg.html and ask him how he made that plot.  He might have exported some data to an external tool like graphviz, and made the plot there.

Comment: I asked Kasra Rafi. He and Jing Tao made the graph of graphs in TikZ from pictures of small graphs (inside the nodes) output by Mathematica.

Comment: Note: a similar question was [asked on Ask Sage](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/38700/plot-graphs-with-graph-in-vertices/).